# Linking pages from index.html in hosting (file manager) directory

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and I have just signed up to ipage hosting. I have uploaded my .html files to a root directory named "Website". I have several pages that need to be linked to the index.html home page. I have written the following code for each file: Blank but this does not seem to be working. I have also tried

```
<li><a href="/website/page2.html">Blank</a></li>
```

which also does not work. When I click on a link from the index.html page this message appears.

Page Not Found
The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please try the following:

If you typed the page address in the Address bar, make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Click the Back button in your browser to try another link.
Use a search engine like Google to look for information on the Internet.

I have tried everything!! Please help!!

Comment: Is the directory named `Website` or `website`? The case might matter depending on the server.

Comment: Just lower case website.

Comment: Can you manually type in the address and access page2.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases not only directory name is case sensitive, but might be that Website directory is your website's root directory. Therefore I would put these links to index.html and test which works:

```
<li><a href="/Website/page2.html">Blank</a></li> 
<li><a href="/page2.html">Blank</a></li> 
<li><a href="page2.html">Blank</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your files are all in the same folder. In that case you can just do the following:

`<li><a href="page2.html">Blank</a></li>`

Since it is in the same directory /Website/ is not needed and will break your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider removing the 1st slash..

Try making your link

`<a href="Website/page2.html">Blank</a>`

Also remember that directory names and files names are case sensitive